# Xml transformation encoding problem

Tags: java, xml, transformation

Hi I have a simple code:

```
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml))
    Document d = documentBuilder.parse(is)
    StringWriter result = new StringWriter()
    DOMSource ds = new DOMSource(d)
    Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer()
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING,"UTF-16")
    t.transform(ds,new StreamResult(result))
    return result.toString()
```

that should trasnform an xml to UTF-16 encoding. Although internal representation of String in jvm already uses UTF-16 chars as far I know, but my expectations are that the result String should contain a header where the encoding is set to "UTF-16", originla xml where it was UTF-8 but I get:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

(also the standalone property seems to be wrong)
The transformer instance is: com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl
(what I think is a default)
So what I miss here?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue after all? I now hit problem too in one app. Really crappy. I have checked the source. The `encoding` value is simply [not passed](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/xsltc/trax/TransformerImpl.java#TransformerImpl.transform%28javax.xml.transform.Source%2Ccom.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.SerializationHandler%2Cjava.lang.String%29) to the translet.

Answer (score 1):

Use a writer where you explicitly declare UTF-16 as output encoding. Try `OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, String charsetName)` which should wrap a`ByteArrayOutputStream` and see if this works.

Comment: Why should this change the encoding attribute in xml? What I want is use a Transformer to change the encoding in header of xml.(not works)

Comment: Because the transformer might be aware of the explicit encoding then?

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a test on my own now. With one minor change:

```
 t.transform(ds,new StreamResult(new File("dest.xml")));
```

I have the same results **but** the file is indeed UTF-16 encoded, checked with a hex editor. For some strange reason the xml declaration is not changed. So your code works.

Comment: Yes my question was about this 'strange reason' my problem is not that the encoding not changes (it works for me as well), but that the xml declaration is not changed... as you wrote too.

Comment: This is somewhat PITA. I would check with Xalan and write to their mailinglist.